# Why does Round function returns different value, when input parameter is passed by a variable

Tags: php, math, types, rounding

In `php` I called `round()` function twice below.

1st call gets `$ppp` parameter, which is `5.585` when printed.

2nd call gets `5.585` as parameter as hard coded.

Why does round function returns 5.59 for the first one and 5.58 for the second one ?

```
$price = 75.3975; 
$ppp = $price - ($price/(1.08));
echo $ppp.'<br>'; //Prints 5.585
echo round($ppp,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN).'<br>'; //Prints 5.59
echo round(5.585,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //Prints 5.58
```

Comment: This seems a lot like the typical 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 issue people face. The *exact* value of `$ppp` might not be exactly `5.585` when calculated in floating-point.

Comment: Just another floating point problem. If you adjust the precision you'll see `$ppp` is slightly above 5.585 and the literal is slightly below. https://3v4l.org/4ecED